# Live server do not load @media from css file with link tag

Tags: html, css, server

Live server do not load @media from css file with link tag.

[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DqAP.png)

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rohh.ru/API/style/module.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rohh.ru/API/style/void.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

[Module API code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1X0p.png)

```
@media screen and (max-width:100vh) {
  .for-desktop{display: none !important;}
  .for-mobile{display: flex;}
}
@media screen and (max-height:100vw) {
  .for-mobile{display: none !important;}
  .for-desktop{display: flex;}
}
```

The general problem is:

I have two types of menus. One for mobile, another for desktop. It is **not working on server only**.

```
<menu class="for-mobile">
<menu class="for-desktop">
```

[STATIC LOCAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxMk7.png)
[DYNAMIC LOCAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9xXV.png)

I do not know even how to Google this issue. Also, help in comments properly retitle this problem.

1. I was trying to make proper formatting:

```
type="text/css"/
```

2. Change orientation landscape to max-width 100vh ...

```
(orientation: landscape)
(max-width:100vh)
```

3. Load it to the proper server with WP or Apache.
4. Open in another browser and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

i think this [article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/) will help you to solve your problem, i hope this help you. you can change your size to pixel (px). you can learn from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php) too, i have try that, and working

Comment: Sorry, it is inappropriate answer. I said before that I have used different formats of media query. (2). First of all I was used orientation query. As you see, this question about server mostly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you’re having with the media queries is using `100vh` and `100vw` for max-width and max-height. Try changing it to use pixels (e.g. `max-width: 400px`)

Comment: Sorry, it is inappropriate answer. I said before that I have used different formats of media query. (2). First of all I was used orientation query. As you see, this question about server mostly.

I need only 2 media query's. Also I am using it 3 years on LAMP, WAMP. All kinds of CMS and go on. 

Now it is not working because I am making this out of main html page through stylesheet, I presume.

Comment: Yes. Just added it to the main page and it working properly with media. It is not working only with media and <link>

Answer (score 0):

It was browsing data. Just clear it and everything will be fine.